# How to localize text in c under windows?

Tags: c, windows, localization

I want to localize text given in a xml structure. A parser for xml is implemented yet, so I can use any c style structure to handle the different texts (texts of same meaning, but in different languages). But what is a good way to realize the localization?

Thanks Rumo

Answer (score 0):

You could read chunks of text from the file and use **string.h** functions to find any specific sub string you're interested in. Take a look on the **strstr** function documentation:

```
const char * strstr ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
char * strstr ( char * str1, const char * str2 );
```